# What does position mean in sql error message?

Tags: sql, oracle

> Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 5374, Sql = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DOC_.....long query)

In the above error message what does position signify? How to go to track that table or position from where the error is coming using this `position=5374`

Comment: This is the entire original Oracle error message ?

Comment: The message usually gives a line number; the position points to a character in that line. In this case, presumably a table name starts as char 5374. Is there a reason you don't format the code into multiple shorter lines?

Comment: Actually the sql is read from .ksh file , upon runnig that script the error is coming. The error message is veru big , table does not exists , i was just curious about what is this position. Is space is also counted as a character ?

Answer (score 3):

As Alex commented, it is a position of the error. You then asked whether spaces are counted; yes, they are.

Have a look at example ran in SQL*Plus: in line #4, I used a column that doesn't exist (`enmae_typo_here`).

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_ename emp.ename%type;
  3  begin
  4    select enmae_typo_here
  5      into l_ename
  6      from emp
  7      where rownum = 1;
  8  end;
  9  /
  select enmae_typo_here
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 10:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ENMAE_TYPO_HERE": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


SQL>
```

As you can see, Oracle points you to exact error position with a asterisk:

```
select enmae_typo_here
             *
```

and says in which line (`4`) and at which position (column) (`10`) (`ORA-06550: line 4, column 10`)I made a mistake.

The same goes for your query; although, it isn't formatted at all so it spans thousands of columns, so you'll have to scroll *far right* to find the culprit.

Comment: But in Oracle error there is no word "position" right ? So this is an error reported not by Oracle I believe...

Comment: It is related to Oracle ("942" being "ORA-00942: table or view doesn't exist"). The OP said that "sql is read from .ksh file , upon runnig that script the error is coming" so you might be right - Oracle message was "wrapped" by Unix.